# Flutter: How to sync data from sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

```
            TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
            bool editState = false;

            StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (context, setState){
                  return AlertDialog(
                      content: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8, left: 8, right: 8),
                                child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: editState ?
                                    TextField(
                                      controller: textEditingController,
                                    ) :
                                    Text(checkpoint["memo"])
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                      child: editState ? Text("Save") : Text("Edit"),
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        if(editState == true){
                                          DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper();
                                          await dbHelper.updateCheckpoint(checkpoint["userkey"], checkpoint["id"], textEditingController.text);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                          setState((){
                                            editState = !editState;
                                          });
                                        }
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                  );
                },
              )
```

This is my code. I want the `Text (checkpoint ["memo"])` to be updated when I type something and click the save button.
I tried using `ChangeNotifierProvider`, but it didn't work. I may have used it incorrectly. So I don't know how to approach this problem. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For text field there is one method [onChanged()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onChanged.html). Which gives you an updated text. You can save that text to some variable and use the same variable to display text where you want to display it. Don't forget to call setState() something like following in [onChanged()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onChanged.html) to update the textfield text.

```
setState(() { _memo = newTextValue; });
```